# error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'. in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I'm using angular7 and I make routing for admin but its giving error 'string is not assignable to type' Anybody can tell what is this error & how can i resolve it?

Error screenshot:-

[image]

admin.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { adminComponent } from './admin.component';

const routes:  Routes =[
    {
        path: 'admin',
        component:adminComponent,
        children: [
            {path: '', component: 'loginComponent', pathMatch: 'full'},
            {path: 'dashboard', component: 'dashboardComponent'}
            //{path: 'login', component: 'loginComponent'}
        ]
    }
];

export const adminComponents = [
    adminComponent
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class adminRouterModule{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component should not be a **`string`**, it is the **`component`** name,

change

**From**

```
  {path: 'dashboard', component: 'dashboardComponent'}
```

**To**

```
  {path: 'dashboard', component: dashboardComponent}
```

Comment: same wiith logincomponent

Answer (score 1):

Remove '' from `component: loginComponent`

```
{path: '', component: loginComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: 'dashboard', component: dashboardComponent}
```